# When overflow Scroll Is Available

Tags: css

I've got a parent DIV. Set with. I then have a inner DIV which is overflow-x: scroll.

It all works perfectly. But I want to display a message ONLY when scrolling is needed.

Is there a CSS or JAVASCRIPT method which can pick up on this without using libraries such as jQuery or Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Look for when I div is wider than the other...

```
 function myFunction() {
        var x = 0;
        var parentWidth = document.getElementById("myDIV").clientWidth;
        var x = document.getElementById("thisDIV").querySelectorAll(".awiderDIV"); 
        if (x[0].clientWidth > parentWidth){
            document.getElementById("scroll").style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("scroll").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```